# Classify phrases as biomedical or non-biomedical

Tags: classification, nlp, text-mining

Words like `myotonic` are biomedical, but words like `new` appear in regular English texts. I can imagine a few ways to classify words into biomedical and non-biomedical. Has this problem been tackled before? Does anybody know any ready-to-use solutions for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There has been work going on in the healthcare domain which involves NLP.

Resources like [Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) have been put together for the exact same purpose.

You can make use of the freely available [Pubmed vectors](http://bio.nlplab.org/) for training your models like maybe a sentence tagging style model for identification. We(my team at work) use them for identification of medical terms like diseases, medicines, etc.

Comment: I don't need advanced identification of disease names or medicines. I only need to determine if a phrase is biomedical or not. Is there a ready to use tool? Could you show an example on how use http://bio.nlplab.org/ to determine whether a phrase is biomedical or not?

Comment: @user1424739 You just need to check if the word exists in the Pubmed vector or not.

Comment: But a word that appears in Pubmed vector does not mean the word is biomedical.

Comment: No. But, you would be close.  [This is the only research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23645553) I found related to this topic.